# How to get_comment_time in Wordpress per comment id?

Tags: php, wordpress

I checked the Codex of Wordpress and it seems like both get_comment_time as well as comment_time do not have the option for extra arguments like a comment_id. This means I can't show the correct time for my comments at this moment.

Is there any way to solve this?

I tried the following, but without luck:

```
        $comment_id = get_comment_ID();
        $test = get_comment_time()->$comment_id;
```

or

```
    $test = get_comment_time($comment_id);
```

And when I try to echo it, it doesn't show anything at all.

When I try to use  it will not show me the correct time of that comment. That's why I thought I should attach it to a comment id, but this seems impossible.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Since the get_comment_time() function does not do much you can easily replace it with this:

```
$comment = get_comment($comment_id);
$date = mysql2date(get_option('time_format'), $comment->comment_date);
```

Obviously this is a basic approach ignoring filters etc.

Comment: This doesn't do what I like to do. I just want to output the time of the comment. Where in your function does it do that? I am calling it using echo $date, but nothing happens...